# Number Sequencing

Tags: sequences-and-series

trying to help my daughter with math - I'm terrible.

The question is which item in the following sequence does not belong and why...

1, 11, 5, 13, 8, 15, 13, 17

If someone could help with the answer and more importantly the "why" we would be very grateful.

Thanks,

D

Comment: Hint: Parity (even/odd)

Comment: Well $8$ is the only even number in the list. Perhaps that's what her teacher had in mind. Some context might help: are there lots of questions along these lines?

Comment: Number $1$ doesn't belong the list because $\zeta(1)$ is undefined while it is defined for other numbers in the list ($\zeta$ is Riemann-Zeta function). I'm posting this just to show how meaningless such questions are. What this question has to do with mathematics? There is no computable solution to this problem. The solution is opinion based. I can claim that answer is any number from the list, according to the axiom of separation, I can provide corresponding statement for each number which makes it unique. (mod ed)

Comment: $8$ is the obvious choice since it's the only even number. Another choice is $13$ since it's the only one that appears more than once. Another choice is $1$ since it's the only one that has no prime factors. Still another choice is $15$ since it's the only one that has more than one  distinct prime factor. The point here is that these kinds of questions have no forced answer.

Comment: assuming elementary math: the odd terms make AP with $d=2$ and the even terms would make AP with $d=4$ if $8$ were $9$...